# Google AppEngine - Django - non-rel - Pycharm : Anyone been able to use PyCharm and Non-rel on GAE?

Tags: django

has anyone used Pycharm on a Google AppEngine project with non-rel?

I've just installed PyCharm and having a hard time getting a working configuration.

Comment: You should probably go into some more detail about the problem you're encountering if you'd like to get some help with this.

Answer (score -2):

I haven't exactly tried PyCharm, but may I suggest my favorite IDE: [Wing IDE](http://www.wingware.com/) that works properly out of the box.